# How can I see a wireless network's frequency and/or channel?

Tags: wireless

NetworkManager is showing a number of different wireless networks available in my neighbourhood.  I would like to know what channels the other wireless networks are operating on.  How can I view these wireless network's channel information?

I am aware of the `iwlist scan` command but it **does not** see most of the networks that NetworkManager sees: the networks shown by running `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` are completely different from NetworkManager's list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use the `nm-tool` command, it shows the information from NetworkManager it self.

`nm-tool` will list all of the visible wifi networks' frequencies.  The command `sudo iwlist frequency` will give you a list of their corresponding wifi channel numbers.

Comment: Awesome, I searched quite a bit for ways to scan for wireless networks and never saw nm-tool mentioned.  Thank you!

Comment: One caveat - If your Internet connection is hooked up directly to your system via a cable modem or DSL and not wireless, you will not receive any other wireless information in your vicinity. These commands will only give you what your direct connection is.